# Cannot Remove Secondary Dynamic IP

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-20.04

I'm running Ubuntu Server 20.04. The system was setup initially with DHCP. I went into /etc/netplan and changed the file to use a static IP, as shown below.

```
network:
  ethernets:
    enp0s4:
      addresses: [10.0.1.9/24]
      dhcp4: false
      gateway4: 10.0.1.1
      nameservers:
        addresses: [8.8.8.8, 4.2.2.2]

  version: 2
```

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vbA8V.png)

The plan has been applied and rebooted multiple times. The new IP works and is valid, but the old DHCP address is still present. I disabled `DHCPCD` with no luck. When I enter `ip a` it shows both the static and dynamic IP. I'm trying to get rid of the secondary dynamic address, but everthing I've tried doesn't seem to work.

```
2: enp0s4: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:a0:98:12:22:95 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.0.1.9/24 brd 10.0.1.255 scope global enp0s4
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 10.0.1.242/24 brd 10.0.1.255 scope global secondary dynamic enp0s4
       valid_lft 81243sec preferred_lft 81243sec
```

[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zse0S.png)

Comment: I'm not familiar with netplan. What's in /etc/network/interfaces ?

Comment: Please copy and paste text whenever possible instead of making screenshots of the text. Many users cannot view images, nor are their contents searchable.

Comment: @FiddleDeDee Nothing. Version 20 doesn't use interfaces, it uses netplan. /etc/network only has if-pre-up.d and if-up.d.

Comment: My goodness, I'm a bit out of date! Is there more than one file in /etc/netplan?

Comment: @FiddleDeDee No, just 00-installer-config.yaml

Comment: Have you checked this link? https://linuxhint.com/setup_static_ip_address_ubuntu/ It says to check that the interface isn't governed by CloudInit - ensure you have set the network config to disable in `/etc/cloud/cloud.cfg.d/subiquity-disable-cloudinit-networking.cfg`

Comment: I found the issue. It looks like a plugin I was using marked my DHCP address as static and caused that conflict. It seems to be working now. I appreciate the help.

Comment: Glad it was sorted.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and running the following help me determine my problem:

```
netplan --debug generate
```

I'd backed up my 50-cloud-init.yaml to _50-cloud-init.yaml which was still be read as a valid yaml file; doh! Renamed it to 50-cloud-init.yaml.bak, rebooted; problem solved.